# Im not sure how to add a while True statement to my code

Tags: python

Hey guys like the title said im not quite sure how to add a while True statement to my code. So far, after the program calculates the answer it goes back to the command prompt and not the menu which is what I want it to do. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
1) Area (Square)
2) Area (Rectangle)
3) Area (Circle)
4) Perimeter (Square)
5) Perimeter (Rectangle)
6) Perimeter (Circle)
7) Exit Program
""")

Choice = input ("1,2,3,4,5,6 OR 7? ")

while True:
    if Choice == "1":
        print ("You have chosen area (Square)")
        length = float(input("input Length?"))
        print ("Area is:" ,  length**2.0)
    elif Choice == "2":
        print ("You have chosen area (Rectangle)")
        length = float (input("input length?"))
        width = float (input("input width?"))
        print ("Area is:" , length*width)
    elif Choice == "3":
        print ("You have chosen area (Circle)")
        radius = float (input("input radius?"))
        print ("Area is:" , (radius**2.0)*3.14)
    elif Choice == "4":
        print ("You have chosen perimeter (Square)")
        length = float(input("Input length?"))
        print ("Perimeter is:" , length*4.0)
    elif Choice == "5":
        print ("You have chosen perimeter (Rectangle)")
        width = float(input("Input width?"))
        length = float(input("Input length?"))
        print ("Perimeter is:" , width*2.0+length*2.0)
    elif Choice == "6":
        print ("You have chosen perimeter (Circle)")
        radius = float(input("Input radius?"))
        print ("Perimeter is:" , 2.0*3.14*radius)
    elif Choice == "7":
        print ("You have chosen to exit")
    exit()
    break
```

Comment: You don't need an exit and your break should be under the last elif, not directly under the while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your break is at the end of the loop, so here is what you're telling the program to do:

```
while True:
    //Choice stuff
    exit the loop
```

Move the `break` and `exit()` inside `elif Choice == "7":`and it will only execute that code when option 7 is chosen.

You only actually need 1 of the escaping functions too. I tend not to use `exit()` and just use `break` - if this is the end of your program, it will exit anyway. If you have more code below, it will be executed. Good practice to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

But you've got to put your `exit` into the `else` statement. And the `break` is not necessary.